# how to get the name of json object from my json array

Tags: java, json, arrays

I am trying to get the name of my json key from my jsonarray but not able to take in java.

> [{"ParamName":"param1","DefaultValue":"","Hidden":"Hidden","LinkedParameter":"city"}]

I just want to take name of key like i only want to take "ParamName" and need to check

if (ParamName == "ParamName") {
Then do this.
}

Comment: Which json library are you using, if any?

Comment: `if (ParamName.equals(ParamName")) {..}`

Comment: How about `jsonObject.keys()` to get an iterator

Comment: i tried this way but its not working

Comment: because everytime i click i get new array and everytime my ParamName changes from capital to small letter and small to capital

Comment: "but its not working" isn't very helpful. You're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this to `JSON` object.

```
 JSONArray json = (JSONArray)new JSONParser().parse("[{\"ParamName\":\"param1\",
    \"DefaultValue\":\"\",\"Hidden\":\"Hidden\",\"LinkedParameter\":\"city\"}]");
 JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) json.get(0);

 if("ParamName".equals(obj.get("ParamName"))){


 }
```